# How do I make "atomic" changes to several ReactiveUI properties?

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I want to change several properties and then notify them all of changes together, so that no notifications go out until the entire state is updated.  Is there a proper way to do this?  If I just do:

```
this.Prop1 = newValue1;
this.Prop2 = newValue2;
```

and the property setters call `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`, then I'll get a notification during the invalid state.  I'd love to write something like:

```
using (new RxTransactionScope()) {
    this.Prop1 = newValue1;
    this.Prop2 = newValue2;
}
```

which would cause them both to be set then both the notifications to fire.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ViewModel {
   ....
    public IDisposable BeginUpdate()
    {
        return new CompositeDisposable(this.SuppressChangeNotifications(), Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Prop1");
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Prop2");
        }));
    }

using(this.BeginUpdate()) 
{
   this.Prop1 = newValue1;
   this.Prop2 = newValue2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (this.DeferChangeNotifications())
{
    this.Prop1 = newValue1;
    this.Prop2 = newValue2;
}
```

Comment: In your example, where do I actually set the properties?

Comment: @Scott: sorry - fixed.